# Unable to figure out how to get Kendo UI Autocomplete to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want a simple autocomplete box hooked up to an MVC method. I created the following but the `name` parameter is `null` and even though I've hard coded some return data, the autocomplete says no data.

The kendo documentation is completely useless. Can anyone give me a simple working example?

```
var catNamesDatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/Cats/GetCats",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "catCode",
            fields: {
                id: { type: "catCode" },
                name: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    }
});

var autoComplete = $("#txtCatSearch").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 3,
    separator: ", ",
    dataSource: catNamesDatasource,
    serverFiltering: true,
    dataTextField: "name"
}).data("kendoAutoComplete");
```

My MVC method is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCats(string name)
{
    var cats = Enumerable.Range(0, 0).Select(e => new { catCode = "C1", name = "Mittens" }).ToList();
    clients.Add(new { catCode = "C2", name = "Fluffywuffy" });

    return Json(cats);
}
```

Comment: Well hard to replicate but: Is Your MVC Action method called? Second thing is that Enumerable.Range(0,0) will return 0 records (but I assume that typo in this example). And also your serverFiltering property should be inside a dataSource [Like they have here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/serverfiltering).

Comment: @NibblyPig Could you please have a look at my new answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input id="test" />
<div id="value"></div>

<script>
    $("#test").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: ["orange", "red", "blue", "green"],
        change: function(e) {
           var value = e.sender.value();
           console.log("change", value);
           $("#value").text(value); 
        }
    });
</script>
```